# Spark: Poor performance on distributed system. How to improve>

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I wrote a simple Spark program, and want to deploy it to the distributed servers. It is pretty simple:

obtain data-> arrange data->train data->reapply to see training result.

The input data is just 10K rows, with 3 features.
I first run at my local machine, using "local[*]". It runs just about 3 mins.
Now when I deploy to a cluster, it runs extremely slow: half an hour without finished. It becomes very slow at the training stage.

I am curious, if I did something wrong. Please help me to check. I use Spark 1.6.1.

I submit:

```
spark-submit --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.5.0  orderprediction_2.11-1.0.jar --driver-cores 1 --driver-memory 4g --executor-cores 8 --executor-memory 4g
```

The code is here:

```
 def main(args: Array[String]) {
    // Set the log level to only print errors
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

    val conf = new SparkConf()
        .setAppName("My Prediction")
        //.setMaster("local[*]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
    val data = sqlContext.read
        .option("header","true")
        .option("delimiter", "\t")
        .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
        .option("inferSchema","true")
        .load("mydata.txt")

    data.printSchema()
    data.show()

    val dataDF = data.toDF().filter("clicks >=10")
    dataDF.show()

    val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
      .setInputCols(Array("feature1", "feature2", "feature3"))
      .setOutputCol("features")

    val trainset = assembler.transform(dataDF).select("target", "features")
    trainset.printSchema()
    val trainset2 = trainset.withColumnRenamed("target", "label")

    trainset2.printSchema()
    val trainset3 = trainset2.withColumn("label", trainset2.col("label").cast(DataTypes.DoubleType))
    trainset3.cache() // cache data into memory
    trainset3.printSchema()
    trainset3.show()

    // Train a RandomForest model.

    println("training Random Forest")

    val rf = new RandomForestRegressor()
      .setLabelCol("label")
      .setFeaturesCol("features")
      .setNumTrees(1000)

    val rfmodel = rf.fit(trainset3)

    println("prediction")
    val result = rfmodel.transform(trainset3)

    result.show()
}
```

**Update:** After investigation, I found it jammed at

```
collectAsMap at RandomForest.scala:525
```

It spent already 1.1 hours on this line, still unfinished yet. The data, I believe is only several Megabyte.

Comment: how many number of executors you are using in cluster? Have you tried to increase executor memory or have you looked at stages where its taking more time in the cluster?

Comment: --driver-cores 1 --driver-memory 4g --executor-cores 8 --executor-memory 4g. Actually, the file is just 180M, so the memory should be more than sufficient enough.

Comment: It was at the training stage., in the decision tree training

Comment: While you specify executor cores and memory, it doesn't look like you specify the number of executors. To help debug this, maybe try with `--num-executors 1` or `2`. It doesn't seem like shuffling or anything should be slowing things down, but it depends on how many executors are being used by default.

Comment: Thanks, I added --num-executors 1. Because this is a very simple job, so 1 is more than enough. I found the it stops at "collectAsMap at RandomForest.scala:525"

Answer (score 1):

You are building a RandomForest made out of 1000 RandomTrees which will train 1000 instances.

In the code `collectAsMap` is the first action, while all the rest are transformations (are lazy evaluated). So while you see it *hanging* at that line it is because now all the `maps, flatMaps, filters, groupBy,` etc are evaluated.

Comment: but why it is so time consuming?